# Plotting bars hist and PDF line (via kdeplot)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot bar hist of interest rates and attach to it a PDF line. I have looked for solutions and found a way with kdeplot.

The result is pretty strange the kdeplot line is much higher than the bars hist and I don't know how to fix it.

After applying kdeplot:

[image: After applying kdeplot:]

Before applying kdeplot:

[image: Before applying kdeplot:]

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
df=pd.read_excel('interestrate.xlsx')

k=0.0005

bin_steps = np.arange(start = df['Interest rate Real'].min(), stop = df['Interest rate Real'].max(), step = k)

ax = df['Interest rate Real'].hist(bins = bin_steps, figsize=[10,5])
ax1 = df['Interest rate Real']

vals = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticklabels(['{:,.2%}'.format(x) for x in vals])
ax.set_yticklabels(['{:,.2%}'.format(x) for x in vals])
ax.set_title("PDF for Real Interest Rate")
#sns.kdeplot(ax1)
```

Comment: You could try to use `sns.distplot(df['Interest rate Real'])` to plot the histogram and the kde together.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet should set you in the right direction (just insert your data):

```
import scipy.stats as st
y = np.random.randn(1000) # your data goes here
plt.hist(y,50, density=True)
mn, mx = plt.xlim()
plt.xlim(mn, mx)
x = np.linspace(mn, mx, 301)
kde = st.gaussian_kde(y)
plt.plot(x, kde.pdf(x));
```

[image]

Alternatively with `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns
plt.hist(y,50, density=True)
sns.kdeplot(y);
```

[image]

or as simple as:

```
sns.distplot(y)
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed. But how to align the kde with a **pandas** histogram?

Comment: @JohanC. It's aligned as you see on the plots, no magic. Use param `density` in `df.hist` method.